# Proper way of handle sealed class property in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, sealed-class

Hey I am working in Android Kotlin. I am learning this [LatestNewsUiState](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow) sealed class example from Android doc. I made my own `sealed class` example. But I am confused little bit, how can I achieved this. Is I am doing right for my scenario or not?

**DataState.kt**

```
sealed class DataState {
    data class DataFetch(val data: List<Xyz>?) : DataState()
    object EmptyOnFetch : DataState()
    object ErrorOnFetch : DataState()
}
```

**viewmodel.kt**

```
var dataMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<DataState>(DataState.EmptyOnFetch)

fun fetchData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = repository.getData()
            result.handleResult(
                onSuccess = { response ->
                    if (response?.items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        dataMutableStateFlow.value = DataState.EmptyOnFetch
                    } else {
                        dataMutableStateFlow.value = DataState.DataFetch(response?.items)
                    }
                },
                onError = {
                    dataMutableStateFlow.value = DataState.ErrorOnFetch
                }
            )
        }
}

fun fetchMoreData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val result = repository.getData()
            result.handleResult(
                onSuccess = { response ->
                    if (response?.items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        dataMutableStateFlow.value = DataState.EmptyOnFetch
                    } else {
                        dataMutableStateFlow.value = DataState.DataFetch(response?.items)
                    }
                },
                onError = {
                    dataMutableStateFlow.value = DataState.ErrorOnFetch
                }
            )
        }
}
```

**Activity.kt**

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.dataMutableStateFlow.collectLatest { state ->
                when (state) {
                    is DataState.DataFetch -> {
                       binding.group.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    DataState.EmptyOnFetch,
                    DataState.ErrorOnFetch -> {
                        binding.group.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I have some points which I want to achieve in the standard ways.

**1.** When your first initial api call `fetchData()` if data is not **null** or **empty** then we need to **show** view. If data is **empty** or **null** then we need to **hide** the view. But if api **fail** then we need to show an **error message**.

**2.** When view is **visible** and view is showing some data. Then we call another api `fetchMoreData()` and data is **empty** or **null** then I don't want to hide view as per code is written above. And If api **fails** then we show **error message**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In point 2, "If api fails then we show error message", do you want to hide the view?

Comment: @ArpitShukla no I don't want to hide view because it already there some data. when second api call

Comment: And if `fetchData()` fails the first time, will `fetchData()` or `fetchMoreData()` be called ever again? (Like is there a retry option?)

Comment: @ArpitShukla if `fetchData()` fails there is no retry options. If `fetchData()` is success than `fetchMoreData()` will call

Comment: What problem do you have in your 1st point? You can display the error msg in `DataState.ErrorOnFetch` block of the `when` statement. Won't that work?